# Create a nested list ordered by foreignkey

Tags: django, django-views

I am attempting to create a list of insurance plans accepted by a doctor, ordered by plan provider. How can I construct a query that allows me to produce a list of results like this:

```
Provider 1
  Plan A
  Plan B
  Plan C
Provider 2
  Plan D
Provider 3
  Plan E
  Plan F
```

given the following (simplified) models:

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=50)

class Plan(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=50)
    provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider)

class DoctorProfile(UserProfile):
    accepted_insurance_plans = models.ManyToManyField(Plan, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are seeking to generate this list for a given DoctorProfile, dp:

```
import itertools
import operator

plans = Plan.objects.filter(doctorprofile=dp).\
           order_by("provider").select_related("provider")
provider_plans = itertools.groupby(plans, operator.attrgetter("provider"))
```

You can then iterate over the plans grouped by provider as follows:

```
for provider, plan_group in provider_plans:
    print provider.name
    for plan in plan_group
        print "  %s"%plan.name
```

DISCLAIMER: I haven't tested this code